# How can I encrypt my pendrive with password?

Tags: password, security, encryption, usb-drive

In windows 7 or windows 8, I can use *BitLocker Drive Encryption* to encrypt and set a password in my pendrive but i am unable to access files of my pendrive in Ubuntu.

Is there is any method to encrypt and set password in my pendrive in Ubuntu while i can access files from both in Ubuntu and Windows.

Please tell me also if there is any method to access files from a drive which is encrypted with *BitLocker*.

Comment: Related http://askubuntu.com/questions/18751/how-to-encrypt-external-devices-using-a-cross-platform-solution and http://askubuntu.com/questions/664088/encrypt-usb-that-is-compatible-with-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and most fail safe way will be to save your files in password protected archive files, 'zip' being the most popular archive file format supporting such protection. This format is supported directly in most OS's including Ubuntu and Windows, without installing any other applications.

If you want complete drive encryption you'll have to install a third party encryption app, which is cross-platform and/or offers dedicated app for the various platforms.

[VeraCrypt](https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/) seems to be the current popular and most reliable(still in active development, is opensource) app for this. Its a fork and a true successor to the previously popular TrueCrypt, which is no longer being developed.

N.B: I haven't personally used VeraCrypt, please see if it caters to your needs

Comment: zip encryption is to bitlocker encryption like a secret decoder ring is to bitlocker encryption