# Make an external drive Ubuntu + Windows accessible

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, restricted-access

just wondering if there is a way to make an external hard drive ubuntu/linux only accessible. So if someone plugs it into windows or mac, it wouldn't show any files or even the drive or show they are locked out.

If not, is there any utility (free/paid) that allows the hard drive contents to be encrypted/locked and it works for at least Linux and windows?

Thanks!

EDIT: I am looking for some utility that works BOTH for Windows and Linux.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll have a go at SuperUser then.

Comment: From the link I gave you first http://askubuntu.com/questions/664088/encrypt-usb-that-is-compatible-with-windows

Comment: Is that what you needed?

Comment: Yes, I think I'll go with VeraCrypt, it looks promising. Thank you for your help!