# Encrypt partition on external HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, encryption

I have an Ubuntu Live disk that I enjoy using on the draw. I also have an external HDD that I have partitioned, one partition for open files that I don't care if people access, one partition that I would like to password protect and encrypt for personal files.

I would like to be able to access these encrypted files from either Windows or Ubuntu. Furthermore, I'd like to hide the encrypted partition as well. I've done something similar several years ago, but those encryption schemes are no longer considered secure.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you in advance for bestowing your knowledge on me! lol

Comment: VeraCrypt does encrypt full partitions but I can't help you that.

Comment: Have you already checked: [How to encrypt external devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500981/how-to-encrypt-external-devices) and [How to encrypt external devices using a cross-platform solution?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18751/how-to-encrypt-external-devices-using-a-cross-platform-solution)? I personally recommend [VeraCrypt](https://lifehacker.com/five-best-file-encryption-tools-5677725/1685273934),  is a cross-platform solution.