# How to choose file system on pendrive only for linux read write only

Tags: usb, filesystem, usb-drive

What I need is to create pendrive that could be only used in linux os. What file system can be picked to be able to use it on any computer with linux?

I noticed ext4 is not good choice for file system on USB.
I need file system for files over 4 GB size.

Comment: "I noticed ext4 is not good choice for file system on USB." why not? been using it for a decade or so without any issue. and if so ...nothing wrong with ext3.

Comment: I too have had no issues with ext4 on USB, been using it exclusively for over a decade

Comment: Are you talkin about running Ubuntu from pendrive or just using it for transportation and storage of data?

Comment: data storage, not bootable ubuntu from pendrive

Answer (score 1):

I beg to differ: ext4 is an excellent choice for USB media. What makes you think it's not?

As for "Linux only", that depends on the level of expertise of the people you want to protect the content against. There is software to make Linux filesystems accessible on Windows, mostly on the level of file managers that have support for them built in. Just using a filesystem type that doesn't work on Windows by default is only a very low-level protection against amateurs.

If you really want your USB stick to be secure against unauthorized access, why not encrypt it? That requires some one-time work to set up the encryption, but once that's done, using it is quite simple.

See [How to encrypt external devices?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500981/how-to-encrypt-external-devices)

Please notice that you will of course have to set up suitable permissions for directories on that USB stick so you your normal user account can actually use it:

```
cd /media/$USER/mystick     # or whatever the volume is named
sudo mkdir mystuff
sudo chown $USER mystuff
```

See also

- https://www.guru99.com/file-permissions.html
- https://linuxhint.com/linux_file_permissions/

Comment: No, you don't. You just need suitable permissions once. If you are fearless, you can also simply grant permission for everyone on that stick: `sudo chmod 777 /media/$USER/mystick/mystuff`. I wouldn't recommend that, though; it's best to set up permissions explicitly. Also, all Linux filesystems have the Linux permission system in common.

Comment: Please read those introductions about file permissions that I linked to. In the best case, you are using the same (numeric) user ID on all your systems; if there are no other user accounts, that's the case anyway. If you are using network user accounts (NIS or LDAP) at work or at university, this needs some more work.

Comment: sorry how stupid of me, I made a typo and command did not work... :D than you for all the help and bearing with my noobity.